# Rails - Checking if an object has a property which starts with a specific character using .where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a database with users. They all have postcodes.

I am trying to use .where to grab all users which are within 100 days old and which have a postcode which begins with "NR".

I tried the below code but I get postgres syntax errors, probably because .where seems to accept database-specific syntax instead of straight-up ruby.

```
users = User.where('created_at < ? and postcode[0..1] = ?', 100.days.ago, "NR")
```

I cannot seem to find anything which would help me out online. I even tried to create an array and iteratively save through records which matched, but then rails couldn't assign the Users to an array either, so I canned it.

Could anybody here give me any guidance?

Comment: I solved it by using substr(postcode, 1,2) = ? instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming you always need to maintain an awareness of what *context* you're writing code for. Often you'll be working with HTML, JavaScript, Ruby and SQL simultaneously, each of which has their own syntax and conventions.

In this case you're working with Postgres SQL, so what you need is a Postgres function to do the work for you. Here's a literal translation:

```
User.where('created_at < ? and LEFT(postcode, 2) = ?', 100.days.ago, "NR")
```

Be sure to familiarize yourself with the [Postgres string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) as there are many of them.

As R_O_R points out in another answer, using `LIKE` is an option here.

Comment: accepted, as this was a better implementation of what I was trying to achieve :) thanks!! :D

Comment: I would prefer to minimize the SQL in my Ruby code.  Arel is nice(made) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

<s>`users = User.where { |u| u.postcode.matches "NR%" && u.created_at <  100.days.ago }`</s>

Not sure where that comes from, so try (more lines though):

```
user_tbl = User.arel_table
u = User.where(user_tbl[:postcode].matches("NR%"))
        .where(user_tbl[:created_at].lt(100.days.ago))
```

Comment: [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) takes block also. I didn't aware of it

Comment: You know, I've done this in a console and saw that it worked and never bothered to look into it.  Is it iterating every entry in the table?

Comment: Myself also not aware of.. I have no clue how it worked.. missing documentation.... it seems.....

Comment: When you ran it in console, did you see any SQL ? If so, show me here in the comment..

Comment: You're right. It's loading all the users then querying after.  Makes sense.  I updated the answer.. Thanks!

Comment: uhuoo.. nice `arel_table`... :0

Answer (score 1):

Write as :

```
users = User.where('created_at < ? AND postcode LIKE ?', 100.days.ago, "NR%")
```

Read [PostgreSQL `LIKE` operator](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/).